# Continuous embedding of fractional Sobolev spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Consider the spaces $H^{1/2}(\mathbb{R}^3), H^{-1/2}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^3)$. Are the continuous embeddings true
$$H^{1/2}(\mathbb{R}^3)\hookrightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)\hookrightarrow H^{-1/2}(\mathbb{R}^3)?$$
If the continuous embeddings are true, are they also dense?

Could anyone help, please? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, of course the embedding are true, just use the definition of the norms in Fourier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As intimated in the comments, use the definition $$H^s(\mathbb{R}^n)=\{u\in\mathcal{S}': \langle\xi\rangle^s\hat{u}\in L^2\}.$$ From here, it's immediately clear that $H^s\subset H^t$ for $s>t,$ owing to the fact that $\langle\xi\rangle^s\geq\langle\xi\rangle^t$ for $s>t.$  In particular, you get your sequence of inclusions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @cmk. 
They are also dense in each other?

Comment: Sure. It's pretty easy to see-think of a dense space that's contained in all of them.

Comment: could you explain me why they are dense in each other. It is not clear for me.

Comment: Smooth, compactly supported functions are contained and dense in both, for example.